# Grails 3 profiles,JSON rendering and One to Many with self

Tags: json, grails, one-to-many, profile

I'm working with gson and web profile.

**My domain is:**

```
package json
import grails.rest.*

@Resource(readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Hero {
    String name
    String data
    String relation
    Book book
    static hasMany = [children: Hero]
```

**My controller is:**

```
package json

import grails.rest.*
import grails.converters.*

class HeroController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    HeroController() {
        super(Hero)
    }
    def show(Hero hero){
        respond hero
    }
}
```

**My gson:**

**hero.gson**

```
import json.Hero

model {
    Hero hero
}

json tmpl.hero(hero)
```

**_hero.gson**

```
import json.Hero

model {
    Hero hero
}

json {
    //data hero.data
    id hero.id
    data(relation: hero.relation)
    name hero.name
    children g.render(hero.children)
}
```

If I run it with restful profile then the all children nodes are rendered correctly.
If I use web profile only two levels deep are rendered.

My expected result is:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "data": {
        "relation": "e"
    },
    "name": "e",
    "children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "data": {
                "relation": "c"
            },
            "name": "c",
            "children": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "data": {
                        "relation": "b"
                    },
                    "name": "b",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
```

Is it possible to do one to many json rendering (as with the restful profile)?
Is there a way to control depth of the rendering?

P.S. I read the documentation and this part is not very clearfor me:

> If you wish for the author to be included as part of the rendering,
>   there are two requirements, first you must make sure the association
>   is initialized.
>
> If the render method encounters a proxy, it will not traverse into the
>   relationship to avoid N+1 query performance problems.     The same
>   applies to one-to-many collection associations. If the association has
>   not been initialized the render method will not traverse through the
>   collection!
>
> So you must make sure your query uses a join:
>
> Book.findByTitle("The Stand", [fetch:[author:"join"]])
>
> Secondly when calling the render method you should pass the deep
>   argument:
>
> json g.render(book, [deep:true])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's possible to render your json using web profile.
I can do it by adding to build.gradle:

```
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"

dependencies {

    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"



bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}
```

and using your code with a little change in the domain class: 
**children lazy: false**

```
@Resource(readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Hero {
    String name
    String data
    String relation
    //Book book
    static hasMany = [children: Hero]

    static mapping = {
        children lazy: false
    }
```

Which will change the fetch mode.
You can consult about fetching here:

[enter link description here](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/fetch.html)http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/fetch.html

http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/guide/single.html#fetching

Comment: it seems that I've added older version: classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.1.*...